# Azure what service wil allow my component to run all day?

Tags: azure

We are a Microsoft Azure shop and so far everything has run as a serverless application triggered via Azure "Logic App". I am new to Azure.

If I want to develop a program that needs to connect to a third-party provider via the SOCKET connection and query/receive streaming data all day long - where can I deploy this component in Azure world to accomplish such a task without creating a virtual server in Azure?
Let's say the requirement for my component is to start at 05:00 and finish running at 23:59. The Component will be running uninterrupted. The only dependency is on the time when it starts and ends.
Can you please point me to the Azure resources that will allow me to do so? I do know how to develop this kind of software and I have done it numerous times(Java, C#, Python). I just do not know enough where in Azure I can schedule it to run the whole day.

Thanks!

Comment: Product/service recommendation questions are expressly off-topic. You can start with the Azure docs that enumerate all available services. You can then choose the best one for you, based on your needs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/app-service/?ref=jimmybogard.com) provides an environment to run your application similar to a VM except that the underlying host is managed for you. Do note that you will be charged for the underlying app service plan and not the number of apps, so even if you have no app running on it, you will still be charged for the compute dedicated to your app service plan.

That being said, if it is possible to convert your solution to be event-based by forwarding the stream data to Event Hubs or have a timer triggered function to read from the stream at an offset (assuming the stream allows it), that would be recommended and allows you to build your solution using serverless options.

Comment: Please don't post answers that just promote a particular service. This is not a valid answer (and this also is not the place to be bringing up pricing). The question is off-topic (recommendation, and not a programming question)

Comment: also, you're proposing an event-driven solution, along with a server less solution - this literally has nothing to do with the OP's question - you're proposing architecture choices to a non-existent problem.